# Are there limits for buckets, files, projects, etc. at Autodesk?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-data-management

Are there any limits for buckets, files, projects or any of that sort?
There is no information about it on https://developer.autodesk.com. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Limit on number buckets, files or projects. So I guess that is very good news for you. I will say be mindful with the number of buckets that will hold your translations (those cost money) so if you want to access them and you have quite a few might be hard to remember where the specific translation is located.

Comment: Good thing, and thanks for the tip! Where did you gather this info?

Comment: I'm a Forge Developer Advocate :), I will suggest that this information is publish somewhere in the Docs. Thank you for the suggestion.